# Android - HttpClient and multi-threading

Tags: android, httpclient

I have an application that uses apache's HttpClient to get websites. It has 2 threads - UI thread (where user can order downloading a subpage) and other that every x seconds refreshes main page by downloading it with use of HttpPost. 
It appears that there is some synchronization problem(query started ends immediately with socket error), when during reloading user starts a download of another page (I use the same DefaultHttpClient for both queries). Important thing is that the page requires cookies (user has its session).
My question is:
Should I use one HttpClient and queue of queries not to let them happen in the same moment?
Or maybe each thread should have it's own HttpClient and they should have common context?
Or there is any other way that eliminates this error?

I also want to ask if you know a faster HTML parser than JSoup. It is pretty fast, I agree, but maybe there's something better?

Comment: I use async tasks - the problem is synchronization...

Answer (score 4):

You can make `HttpClient thread safe` by specifying a thread safe client manager. (`Threadsafe` in the sense that two or more threads can interact with it without getting above error message)

http://foo.jasonhudgins.com/2009/08/http-connection-reuse-in-android.html

Answer (score 0):

You should have HTTPClient for each thread. If you are doing any common task (Might be danger).
To make it thread safe you should put synchronized block at method level or where you have common task to do.

Recommendation : While working with thread keep the tasks as much separated as possible. If at all you have some common task , make use of synchronized block